# When I resize the browser window, the image stays the same

Tags: html, css

When I resize my browser, image stays same and my site looks awful, so how can I fix it, so that when I size my browser `.banner` the image is responsive

```html
<img class="banner" src="banner.svg" alt="">
```

```css
.banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex:none;
  float:right;
  z-index: -1;
  top:-50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `<img>` inside a `<div>` like so ([working CodePen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/MWaRgRZ)):

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css,

`flex:none;` makes it so that the image won't shrink, which makes it overflow when you resize your browser window, try removing `flex:none;` out of your code like so

```css
.banner {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -50px;
}
```

You can read more about flex properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `max-width` property is used, the CSS is telling the object can be maximum `100%` of the screen width. But that also means that you can be smaller. Either try:

```css
.banner {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex:none;
  float:right;
  z-index: -1;
  top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="banner" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
```

In the above, I added a `min-width: 100%;` and kept `max-width: 100%;` so that the size is always `100%`. If you don't like that, try:

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex:none;
  float:right;
  z-index: -1;
  top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" class="banner" alt="" />
```

Here, I added only a `width: 100%;` and took out the `max-width: 100%;` which makes the width always `100%` of the screen width. These should help.

But, say you want the width to be `100%`, but you don't want the `img` smaller than `100px`, or larger than `500px`:

```css
.banner {
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  flex:none;
  float:right;
  z-index: -1;
  top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="banner" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
```

The `min-width` and `max-width` property specifies the "edges of the container", or the parameters of the width. Not the actual width. You can read more about some of these properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try `width : 100%` and remove other attributes and check again if it works